# Shiny radio buttons - Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, radio-button, bigdata

**Hello**

I'm having some trouble with an error *'aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data'* for a reactive ggplot in a shiny.

First, a little bit of info on the structure of the data:

I'm using a big dataset, with **lots** of variables. As seen in the code below, I've built a reactive dataset to first filter by geography (higher and lower levels) and service type. The user then has the option to choose a Y variable using a radioButton input. In the example given below, the Services variable is the total number of commercial services being run by brands in the area, whereas the Brand variable is a list of Brands operating in that locality. As an example:

```
"Brand"     "Services"    "Rating"
  A         25            Good
  B         12            Good 
  C         45            Poor
  ...       ...           ...
```

I'm want my Y variable made changeable according to a radioButton input. There are two possible variables, one is numerical (i.e. 'Services' or number of services) and the other is categorical (i.e. commercial brands). Both vectors are the same length. In sum, I want the Y axis to show a count of either variables (i.e. No. Services or No. Brands).

However, when I change the radioButton selection, the visual does not update and (as seen in the images 1 and 2 below) the Y axis does not format properly.

What am I missing?

**Image 1: Selected Services**
[image]

**Image 2: Selected Brands**
[image]

**UI**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Test App"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(id = "sidebar",
                   uiOutput("geography1"),
                   uiOutput("geography2"),
                   uiOutput("service"),
                   radioButtons("y", "Choose Y variable",
                                c("Services",
                                  "Brands"),
                                selected = "Services")
      )
         mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                        tabPanel("Visual", plotOutput("plot", height = "500px")),
                        tabPanel("Underlying data", dataTableOutput("table"))
         )
      )
   )
   )
)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$geography1 = renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "geog1",
                  label = "Select geography (higher):", 
                  choices = as.character(unique(Test$Geog1)),
                  selected = "Region")
   })
   datasub <- reactive({
      req(input$geog1)
      filter(Test, Geog1 %in% input$geog1)
   })

   output$geography2 = renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "geog2", 
                  label = "Select geography (lower):", 
                  choices = unique(datasub()[,"Geog2"]),
                  selected = unique(datasub()[,"Geog2"])[1]) 
   })
   datasub2 <- reactive({
      req(input$geog2)
      filter(datasub(), Geog2 %in% input$geog2)
   })

   output$service = renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "service",
                  label = "Select Service Type:",
                  choices = unique(datasub2()[,"Sub_type"]),
                  selected = unique(datasub2()[,"Sub_type"])[1])
   })
   datasub3 <- reactive({
      req(input$geog2)
      filter(datasub2(), Sub_type %in% input$service)

   })

   y <- switch(input$y, 
               "Services" = datasub3()$Services,
               "Brands" = datasub3()$Brands)

   # Plot
   output$plot = renderPlot({

      ggplot(datasub3(), aes(x = Overall_rating, y = input$y, fill = Overall_rating))+
         geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
 scale_fill_manual(name = "Overall Service Rating", values = colours)

   })

   # Generate an data table view of the data ----
   output$table <- renderDataTable({
      datasub3()[,1:9]
   }) 

      shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Image 3: Example of Desired Outcome**
   [image]

Comment: In `ggplot` try `aes_string(x="Overall_rating", y=as.character(input$y), fill= "Overall_rating")`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, the code returns: "Object Overall_rating not found".

Comment: Can you please provide reproducible data set

Comment: You are missing some parenthesis/brackets. Could you please make sure that your code is running properly?

Comment: @A.Suliman I can only provide you with a sample dataset. Is this okay?

`Sample_data <- data.frame(
   Geog1 = c("Region","Region","Region","Region","Region","Region"),
   Geog2 = c("North West","North West","North West","North West","North West","North West"),
   Service_type = c("Shops","Shops","Shops","Shops","Shops","Shops"),
   Services = c(45,25,25,15,40,23),
   Brands = c("Brand A","Brand B","Brand C","Brand D","Brand E","Brand F"),
   Overall_rating = c("Good","Good","Poor","Okay","Very Poor","Okay","Unrated")
)`

Comment: @Ozan147 if I just substitue `input$y` for, say, `Services` the code runs perfectly without any issues. Can you tell me where I'm missing parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `switch`, which should define as below inside a `reactive` expression

```
y <- reactive(switch(input$y, 
                "Services" = datasub3()$Services,
                "Brands" = datasub3()$Brands))
```

`ggplot` call will be

```
ggplot(datasub3(), aes(x = Overall_rating, y = y(), fill = Overall_rating))
```

Provided data set does not include `Sub_type` variable, hence I work with datasub2(). But if you counter any issues let me know.

## Update

```
  ggplot(datasub3(), aes(x = Overall_rating, y =y(), fill = Overall_rating))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Overall Service Rating", values = colours) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Services), angle=00, hjust= 0.5, vjust=-1, cex=5)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I should've said, that the 'Sub_Type' variable is actually refering to Service_type variable. However, I tried to run the code like you said and it's throwing the following error = `Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object`. Any ideas? Thanks Suliman

Comment: *جزاك الله خير, I should say

Comment: Sorry I missed `y` before () inside `ggplot`. But it works fine for me, try to remove the server side and added back one by one to check where the error is generated. It is my pleasure, و اياك ;)

Comment: That works, الحمد لله, the only issue I'm having now is that the Y axis is displaying the names of the Brands rather than the count of the Brands for each Rating category. Does this make sense? E.g. Y axis to display the number of Brands with Good rating etc.

Comment: Sorry brother let me clarify:

When I select the Services button, الحمد لله, the Y axis displays the number of services by the Rating (X axis). However, when I select the Brands button, the Y axis displays all of the names of the Brands, but I want the Y axis to show the **number of Brands** against the Rating. 

So the radioButtons allow the user to see: (a) Number of Services by Rating or (b) Number of Brands by Rating. Because the count of Services is distinct from the count of Brands. Does that make more sense? Apologies if it's not brother

Comment: Aha in that case, I think you will need a new data frame for the count of Brands by Rating if the user chose Brands. Am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174651/discussion-between-pryore-and-a-suliman).